# Azure automation - Graphical PowerShell script run parallel?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-automation

Can anyone confirm Graphical PowerShell script run parallel or not? I have PowerShell scripts using power shell scripts I created graphical runbook as below screenshot and when I checked verbose log it seems it run sequential only.

[image]

But Asper Microsoft it run parallel.

[image]
so Is there any configuration to make it parallel run?

My requirement is out of 3 scripts, two scripts run parallelly and one script run only when first 2 scripts are completed. If we have any alternative solution it also accepted.

Answer (score 0):

- The powershell runbooks are based on windows powershell workflows thus we can run the scripts parallel.
- This is achieved using the keyword `Parallel` in the script block and everything under the parallel script block will be run parallel and you can state activities outside the block too since you want one of the activities not to be run parallelly.

```
 Parallel { 
                 <activity 1>
                <activity 2>
               }
<activity 3 >
```

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-types#powershell-workflow-runbooks) on powershell workflow

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-powershell-workflow#use-parallel-processing) on the parallel processing